# props showing error to read in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am new to react and I am passing a variable to a child component in react like this:

```
<div>
            <TablePage
              actionForm={this.handlerinfo}
              disable={this.handledisable}
              resetForm={this.resetForm}
              reportList={this.state.reportList}
            />
          </div>
```

I am passing reportList variable object to table page

The table page component is like this:

```
class TablePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ReportList: '',
    };
  }
  Info = () => {
    this.props.disable();
    this.props.actionForm();
    console.log('ReportList=' + this.props.reportList[0].TDC);

    
    
    
  };

  reset = () => {
    this.props.resetForm();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardBody> 
                <Table striped>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Mark</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>@mdo</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Jacob</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>@fat</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Larry</td>
                            <td>the Bird</td>
                            <td>@twitter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </Table> */}
          <Row>
            <Col style={{ marginLeft: '0.15rem' }}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} onClick={this.reset} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          Approval Table
          <span style={{ float: 'right' }}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} onClick={this.Info} />
          </span>
          <Table hover>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>TDC</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td>{this.props.reportList[0].TDC}</td> 
                
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Jacob</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
                <td>@fat</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Larry</td>
                <td>the Bird</td>
                <td>@twitter</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default TablePage;
```

When I am console.logging this value this.props.reportList[0].TDC to console. It is showing the correct value . However when I am trying to add the same in the render function like so:

```
<td>{this.props.reportList[0].TDC}</td>
```

It is showing cannot read value of undefined TDC. How do I make this work and am confused why the same function is not working in different places. It is working in the info function giving correct console log value. However it is not working in render for

This is where I am declaring the results getting values through web api sql table:

```
getTableValue = () => {
    this.setState({ dataLoading: true });

    axiosAPI.post('api/observation/GetTableValue').then(response => {
      var rows = [];

      var rowdata = response.data;
      //console.log('ResponseData=' + response1);
      //console.log('ORGUNITTEST=' + rowdata.OrgUnit);

      rows.push({
        OrgUnit: rowdata.OrgUnit,
        TDC: rowdata.TDC,
        CustCode: rowdata.CustCode,
        DestCode: rowdata.DestCode,
        EMV: rowdata.EMV,
        Service: rowdata.Service,
        SPCCode: rowdata.SPCCode,
        SPCode: rowdata.SPCode,
        Remarks: rowdata.Remarks,
        Stage: rowdata.Stage,
        Cost: rowdata.Cost,
        SAPUpdate: rowdata.SAPUpdate,
        Active: rowdata.Active,
        CreatedBy: rowdata.CreatedBy,
        CreatedOn: rowdata.CreatedOn,
        UpdatedBy: rowdata.UpdatedBy,
        UpdatedOn: rowdata.UpdatedOn,
      });

      this.setState({ reportList: rows });
      this.setState({ dataLoading: false });
    });
  };
```

Comment: `this.state.reportList` is likely undefined or unpopulated on the initial render and then later is defined when you inspect it in the console. Can you provide more of the parent code that is declaring, and updating, the `this.state.reportList` value being passed as a prop?

Comment: Hi Reese Updated the question

Comment: How can it be defined in one place and not defined in other?

Comment: I was talking about this.props.reportList[0].TDC

Comment: What I am not understanding is that when I do console.log in a function in here

Comment: Info = () => {
    this.props.disable();
    this.props.actionForm();
    console.log('ReportList=' + this.props.reportList[0].TDC); it shows the value bbut not in render

Comment: So you are saying the value doesnt arrive by then? If so how do I work around it?

Comment: This will show the value?

Comment: the code is not working in render it shows error can you give an alternative answer

Comment: Please share all relevant code then. Can we see the parent component and where it declares `reportList`, and all the functions that update that state so that we can reproduce what the value is when `this.state.reportList` is passed to `TablePage` as a prop?

Comment: The function is the same as above. The only thing which needs to be added is the declaration which is reportList: '', in this.state in the dashboard component

Comment: is there a way I can share the code with you?

Comment: Ah, so `this.state.reportList` is initially an empty string `''`? This would be why `this.props.reportList[0].TDC` throws an error on the initial renders until the state is updated. `this.props.reportList[0]` is attempting to access character at index `0` of `''` which is undefined, which is ok until you attempt to access a `TDC` property of an undefined value. This throws the error.

Comment: so what should I do in this case?

Comment: Basically what I said earlier, guard against the null/undefined access. `this.props.reportList?.[0]?.TDC` or `this.props.reportList && this.props.reportList[0] && this.props.reportList[0].TDC`.

Comment: how do I put it in render the question mark in render shows error

Comment: I tried the second method its working thanks a lot

Comment: could you also explain what you are doing here:this.props.reportList && this.props.reportList[0] && this.props.reportList[0].TDC??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can guard against null and undefined object accesses using null-checks/guard-clauses or using the [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) if your browser version supports it.

- null-check/guard-clause

  ```
   this.props.reportList
   && this.props.reportList[0]
   && this.props.reportList[0].TDC
  ```

  This pattern is to check that each more deeply nested property exists (i.e. is truthy) before accessing more deeply. As you can see it can become quite verbose.
- Optional Chaining operator

  ```
   this.props.reportList?.[0]?.TDC
  ```

  This pattern is the same as above but bails on accessing any deeper when it hits a null or undefined value.